# Search and populate value in listbox

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOTAU.jpg)I am trying to write codes which will enable me to search for value and populate result/s in a list box. My serial number is on Column `AB`. My search Columns are from `A` to `D`.

As soon as I click on search, the search doesn't not match. Here is my code.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
Dim shTOF As Worksheet 'TOF sheet
Dim shSearchData As Worksheet
    
Dim iColumn As Integer 'To hold the seleceted column number in TOF
Dim iTOFRow As Long 'To store the last non-blank row number available in TOF sheet
    
Dim iSearchRow As Long 'To hold the last non-black row number available in Searchdata sheet
    
Dim sColumn As String 'To store the column selection
Dim sValue As String 'To hold the search text value
    
Set shTOF = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("T.O.F")
Set shSearchData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Searchdata")
    
iTOFRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("T.O.F").Range("ab" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
sColumn = UserForm10.TOFSEARCHComboBox1.Value
sValue = UserForm10.TOFSEARCH.Value
    
iColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sColumn, shTOF.Range("A8:D8"), 0)
'Remove Filter from Database worksheet
    
If shTOF.FilterMode = True Then
    shTOF.AutoFilterMode = False
End If
    
'Apply filter on Database Worksheet
If UserForm10.TOFSEARCHComboBox1.Value = "No." Then
    shTOF.Range("A1:D" & iTOFRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:=sValue
Else
    shTOF.Range("A8:D" & iTOFRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:="*" & sValue & "*"
End If
     
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, shTOF.Range("C:C")) >= 2 Then
    'code to remove the previouse  data from searchdata worksheet
    shSearchData.Cells.Clear
     
    shTOF.AutoFilter.Range.Copy shSearchData.Range("A8")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
     
    iSearchRow = shSearchData.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'change later on
    
    UserForm10.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 29
    UserForm10.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "30,50,40,40,35,43,43,28,25,25,25,25,37,50,45,55,70,60,47,35,35,40,40,40,40,50,60,160,50"
    
    If iSearchRow > 1 Then
        UserForm10.ListBox1.RowSource = "searchData!A8:D" & iSearchRow
        MsgBox " Records Found."
    End If
Else
    MsgBox " No Record Found."
End If
    
shTOF.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: **1.** If you want to show only A-D in the listbox then why do you have 29 columns? **2.** Why not search for the serial number in Column AB using [.Find](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) and then work with that row? **3..** Also it would really help you can show how your worksheet looks and what is the result that you are expecting in the listbox.

Comment: Hi Rout, thank you for respond highly appreciated.  i am very new to VBA., i want to display row from A to Ab in a listbox. "A-D" will be my filter column. how do i attach my sheet on comments

Comment: Can you upload the file in any file sharing platform like wikisend.com or onedrive or dropbox and then share the link here?

Comment: Good evening Rout, thank you once more. the file is available on drobox the link is attached herein below:  
thank you once more again  https://www.dropbox.com/s/tg1ce2r6qod47ng/Data%20Base%20Quantities_3300.xlsx.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: If you do not mind me saying, your code is in a huge mess :D. **1.** Ok What values are you putting in `TOFSEARCH` textbox and `TOFSEARCHComboBox1`? **2.** Next when you run the code what are you expecting to populate in the listbox and what exactly is populating?

Comment: thank you @Siddhart Rout..  TOFSEARCH = i want to type in the search value to filter in column a to d. TOFSEARCHComboBox1 i want to select the value which will filter the column. when i run the code i want to populate the row which match the value i am searching . e.g under TOFSEARCHcombobox1 i will select No. then in TOFSEARCH i will type in 7797 then the listbox should populate row no.16. iam not sure if you understand what i am trying to explain

Comment: Oh yes, I absolutely understood what you are trying to do :) **1.** BTW It will never be `No.` in the combobox and hence `If UserForm10.TOFSEARCHComboBox1.Value = "No." Then` will never be true. And that is because your combobox has "No" in the dropdown and not `No.` **2.** When I use `7797` and `No`. I do get row 16 in the listbox

Comment: Thank you sooo much it worked. however, if i select start or end nothing is populated.

Comment: @Sidharth Rout do mind if you, with the above problem also

Comment: `if i select start or end nothing is populated. –` What do you mean?

Comment: under TOFSEARCHcombobox1, if i select option start or end then type in a figure in TOFSEARCHBOX nothing is populated in the list box. thank you @Siddharth Rout again for kindness.

Comment: That is because there is no value which is the same as `7797` in Col 3 (Start)? Also it is a numeric field. You cannot use "*" for that. Something like `Criteria1:="99.000"` will work

Comment: good evening @sidharth Rout, no luck with Criteria1:="99.000"

Comment: I tested it with "99.000" and it works :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout i tried the following: shTOF.Range("A8:AB" & iTOFRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:="99.000" & sValue & "99.000"

Comment: Try `shTOF.Range("A8:AB" & iTOFRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:="99.000"`

Comment: @SiddharthRout it almost worked then i am getting this https://www.dropbox.com/s/tnohs34dypfi445/excel.JPG?dl=0

Comment: Slightly busy today and over the weekend. I would recommend stepping through the code to check how to [debug](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) the code and make it behave the way you want it :)

Comment: okay thank have fun enjoy your weekend